# how to open many exe programs by bat file using ranges

Tags: file, batch-file

i have this files here about three hundred file.

```
form1.exe
form2.exe
form3.exe
form4.exe
form5.exe
form6.exe
form7.exe
form8.exe
form9.exe
at
form300.exe
```

i need batch file has a text input to run form3.exe at form7.exe and  another example run from form212.exe at form300.exe

i coded this may it help

```
set /P from=from: %=%
set /P to=to: %=%
start Form%from%.exe at form%to%.exe
```

example

```
first input : 3
second input : 7
this will open form3.exe form4.exe form5.exe form6.exe and form7.exe
```

any help please

Comment: Please calm down and use more words and less exclamation marks to explain!

Comment: sorry .. i fixed my words

Comment: Run `for /?`.  It should help you get started.  You most likely want the /L option.

Comment: i don't understand you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will launch all the form*.exe in the ranges you enter.

If you want to launch them sequentially, instead of all at once, then used the  `/w` switch in the start command.

```
@echo off
set /P "from=from: "
set /P "to=to: "
for /L %%a in (%from%,1,%to%) do start "" Form%%a.exe
```